# SharePoint View Refilter

Tags: list-view, filter

Does anybody have the issue of re-filtering when in a view in SharePoint?

For Example, I'm in a view and I filter my name but when I close/save I have to re-filter back to my view..

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. Are you trying to edit the view and add the filter?

Comment: Let's say I need to change something in my site page. I first want to filter by things that match a certain field. Then I go into edit a certain program, etc. I close and save and I have to re filter the same site page and it's a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need to do is create a view with your filtering already in place.

If you are using SharePoint 2013 you should be able to create a view, either public or private.  Private may be a good idea if the view is filtering to your name and will only be useful to you.

You can create views from list settings.  If the person who created the list enabled an option, after you filter the view you may also see an option to save the view, with your filters.  If this option is turned on you will see a SAVE THIS VIEW option to the right of the list search box at the top of the list.

Comment: Amal Hashim - please help me understand why you edited my post.  I couldn't find anything in the "How do I write a good answer" article about it not being acceptable to remind people to accept your answer.

Comment: I believe Josh answered the above question and I want to better understand the last part. I know how to create a view from list but where is the save filter option for an individual that visits the page?

Comment: I am using 2013 on premise and when I filter or sort a view a SAVE THIS VIEW option appears to the right of the list search box at the top of the list.  

I can't remember at the moment what option is required.  If you don't get it figured out, let me know and I will look more.

Comment: Josh Swearingen - I actually tried doing this but for some reason I could not locate SAVE THIS VIEW. I actually found another way to do this and this is by clicking the dialog box and this saves my filtering option.

Comment: Maybe we are on different versions with different behaviors.  As mentioned I am on 2013 on premise.  I think our patch level is from early 2016.

Comment: I believe you are correct.